# refraction and caustics in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to model this Fiji bottle with 'fake' refraction, it looks fine in the viewport:

[image: viewport]

But in the rendered result it looks very grainy and the refraction is lost:

[image]

Should i give up trying to achieve this in cycles?

Comment: why fake the caustics in cycles? unless you are using eevee, because glass materials might be glitchy sometimes...

Comment: Caustics in cycles have always been quite limited. Try a different render engine, like lux core, that can do proper caustics.

Comment: Refraction is lost in render thanks to enabled Solidify for rendering. It generates thickness of the bottle = it is seen as empty by render, but for Viewport the modifier is disabled = by renderer seen as filled volume.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting this so I can post the pics - if it ends up being no good, i'll delete this answer. Here are a just a couple of things you can try.

Firstly, make sure both Reflective and Refractive Caustics are enabled in the Render Properties tab:

[image: Refract]

Also, in Material Properties (for each material used), make sure "Multiple importance" is selected, and "Homogeneous" is disabled.

[image: MultipleImp]

Lastly, if you're using a denoiser, try turning it down by about half and see if that's what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove your Solidify modifier.

Or just click that little camera icon to hide it in the render.

It's disabled in the viewport, so you don't see it, but when you render, it's still activated.